# Laravel crashing the whole system after using clear:config

Tags: linux, laravel

I'm using linux mint 18.2. After using the following command to each time I enter `localhost:8000` my entire system crashes when my laravel is running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

My laravel version is 5.6.

Edit: After multiple restarts and running the command over and over again the system seems to be working now!

Comment: Did the `php artisan config:clear` command complete? Your system crashes while your Laravel app builds `cache`?

Comment: The command was complete, I got an ok message as far as I remember.